# Refresh view after action in Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse, view, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am programming an Eclipse RCP application.
I have a View on the left and an editor on the right. The view is a menu. With a click on a button in the menu, the editor should open AND the view should change. The editor opens after the click but the view does not change.

Do I have to close the menu-view and open a new one? If yes, how?

If i write page.showView(ID_of_my_view_class.ID) before page.openEditor(..) it opens a new tab next to the displayed console with the logs.

current code:

```
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    this.log.info(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " called");
    IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event);
    IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
    KuenstlerEditorInput input = new KuenstlerEditorInput(new Kuenstler());
    try {
        page.openEditor(input, KuenstlerEditor.ID);
    } catch (PartInitException e) {
        MessageDialog.openError(window.getShell(), "Error",
                "Editor f¸r K¸nstler konnte nicht geˆffnet werden: "
                        + e.getMessage());
        this.log.error(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

When I start the program, it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1faPT.png
When I do the page.showView(the_ID.ID) command, it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsoP9.png

The view should appear on the left, instead of the menu with all the buttons.

Comment: What is the perspective you are using? If you have your own perspective, you should be able to set the location of the view when the perspective is setup. Otherwise, I think you (but an more sure) you should be able to add layout information for your view to the active perspective.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my question below the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `org.eclipse.ui.perspectives` extension point to create a perspective, and then provide an implementation of `IPerspectiveFactory` which will allow you to define the location of the named views that you create.

Answer (score 0):

Create or get an Object of your Project and then do this:
(Works only with the Navigator-view)
project.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, null);

Comment: there's no need for you to close and reopen your View.